# WordPress Page Builder is duplicating Divs

Tags: php, wordpress, web

It's been a while since I've been here but again, I need some help big time with a very annoying issue.

I've installed a theme on WordPress, which is awesome but the problem lies with the page builder as it's starting to duplicate a `Div` inside the original `Div`. Example just below:

```
<div class="sub-title">
<div class="sub-title">
<div class="sub-title">
<h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #c0c0c0;">WEBSITE DESIGN </span></h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #808080;">So you already know we're a creative design agency, but here is info on where we've come from and where we are heading</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So using the page builder, I add elements which form the design and layout, text blocks and etc. I save, but then as soon as I add another element and save that one, it's already duplicated the `Div`, and repeats the action again for another element too. Therefore, every time something is added, it will duplicate the `Div`.

The `Div` already has specified padding, so another duplicate of that `Div` inside, is just bulking up the padding lots, causing the layout to be super thin!

I think the problem lies in `shortcodes.php` but I've seen some people using PHP code in `functions.php`.

Comment: Is it to do with $output ?

Answer (score 1):

Think I cracked the issue! Might be useful for someone else in the future:

When adding an element in a Column, within the Page Builder, for the Special Title it will give you a field and then the text area below. If you enter both Title and Content into the text box, it will strangely start duplicating the ID called sub-title, which is the problem.

So, to fix this, delete the element inside the Column, then re-add it but make sure you enter the Title in the field given, then the Content in the text area below.

Seems to be behaving itself now... I think the Shortcodes.php is set up so when it detects a H tag, it automatically assigns a Div...

Answer (score 1):

For my case it was about having 2 cache management plugin, so i uninstalled one and all was fine again.